# Pass data to all views AND use them in routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've followed this documentation to pass data to all of my views:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

However, it doesn't let me access the variables in my routes file.

How can I pass a variable to all of my views AND be able to use it in my routes file across all of my routes?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are trying to do? And what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about your process. The purpose of passing a certain piece of data to all views is because that value is relevant to the view, not the route or controller action. For example, page titles or showing the user the current date at the bottom of the page.

To do what you want, take a look at the API documentation for [Illuminate\View\View](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/View/View.html) and you will see functions *offsetGet* and *offsetSet*.

Here's an example:

**app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('title', 'Qevo');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**resources/views/example.blade.php**

```php
<h1>{{ $title }}</h1>
```

**app/Http/routes.php**

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    // view has to be created for shared data to be set
    $v = view('example');

    // get the value of the shared data
    $page_title = $v->offsetGet('title');

    // set a new value
    $v->offsetSet('title', $page_title . ' helps');

    return $v;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Session (or caching the data)

I think using sessions is the best way here

lets suppose you want to add somedata to the Current user session

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
```

now you can access this in your View like this

```
Session::get('key');
```

and inside your controller/routes file

```
$value = Session::get('key');
```

This way the data is available inside controller , routes file and views

Comment: What happens if some of the user data is changed (for example, if the user changes their settings)? Wouldn't that data be cached, and therefore wrong unless the cache was updated?

Comment: thats in case you use cache, you can clear the cache , you can create a model observer that clears the cache oninsert/update ..etc, same goes for sessions, everytime the user makes changes, in the sametime update the session value